# What's considered a normal fan speed on ThinkPad?

Tags: thinkpad, fan

I'm under impression what one of recent software updates could have messed with my fan speed, but I'm not sure, since I don't use thinkpad often now, and it could be that fan was always at that speed.

I have constant fan speed at ~3550 rpm, with no load. Is it the same for other users?

```
Core 0:        +55.0°C  (high = +86.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 1:        +58.0°C  (high = +86.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
temp1:        +51.0°C  (high = +95.0°C, hyst =  +3.0°C)
fan1:        3578 RPM
temp1:        +56.0°C  (crit = +98.0°C)
```

CPU is 92.5 idle here.

Interestingly, when coming from hibernate state, fan is at 1800 rpm, but a single load increase triggers fan to spin up to 3900 rpm for load duration, then it refuses to go to the same 1800 rpm and stays at 3500.

Ubuntu 20.04, 5.4.0-70-generic, Thinkpad T420.

Comment: May I ask how did you obtain that output?

Comment: @Levente by running `while true ; do sensors | egrep '(Core|temp1|fan1)' ; echo " ====== " ; sleep 1 ; done`

Comment: Ah, but it never ends :) Other than that, fancy and useful :) Ah; it monitors the change in time, as I understand. Anyhow, the key learning for me was `sensors`.

Answer (score 0):

Fan speed varies among the different thinkpads, but 3000rpm is rather fast. I'd advise to install thinkfan. Since TP42 (still running for 15 years now) I'm using these settings in `/etc/thinkfan.conf`:

```
(0, 0,  44)
(1, 40, 60)
(2, 50, 61)
(3, 52, 63)
(4, 56, 65)
(5, 59, 66)
(7, 63, 32767)
```

making the device silent with temperatures below 65°C

Thinkfan for Ubuntu is documented [here](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/thinkfan.1.html)